# Solving a Sudoku Puzzle Recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to solve a Sudoku Puzzle recursively, Yet the puzzle seems to get into a recursive loop continuously in instances where a row contains duplicate values > 1.

Any input where there is a duplicate in a box, row, column get suck in infinite loops, rather than my recursive method `solvePuzzle` failing.

Examples of failed input are...

#### Same Box

`input = "011"`

```
 0 1 1|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
------+-----+------
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
------+-----+------
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
```

#### Same Row

`input = "0100001"`

```
 0 1 0|0 0 0|1 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
------+-----+------
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
------+-----+------
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
```

#### Same Column

`input = "01000000000000000000000000001"`

```
 0 1 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
------+-----+------
 0 1 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
------+-----+------
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
 0 0 0|0 0 0|0 0 0
```

It otherwise successfully solves other instances. Looking through the debugger, it seems that the stack never progresses beyond row 1. I'm lost to figure out where in my logic I've gone wrong to make it stuck.

The Recursive method is below, I'll include my declarations and implementation for reference at the bottom.

### Solve Puzzles

```cpp
bool Puzzle::solvePuzzle(int row, int col) {
   int next_row = nextRow(row, col);
   int next_col = nextCol(col);

   if (row == 9) {
      return true;
   }

   if (m_board[row][col].isFixed()) {
      return solvePuzzle(next_row, next_col);
   }

   for (int val = 1; val <= 9; val++) {

      if (set(row, col, val) && solvePuzzle(next_row, next_col)) {
         return true;
      }
      else {
         m_board[row][col].setValue(0);
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

### Declarations

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <iostream>


class Puzzle
{
private:
   class Square {
      int m_value;
      bool m_is_fixed;

   public:
      // CONSTRUCTOR
      Square() { m_value = 0; m_is_fixed = false; };

      Square(int value) { m_value = value; m_is_fixed = (value > 0) ? true : false; };

      // DESTRUCTOR
      ~Square() { m_value = 0; m_is_fixed = false; };

      // ACCESSORS
      int getValue() const { return (m_value > 0) ? m_value : -1; };

      int getTrueValue() const { return m_value; }

      // MUTATORS
      void setValue(int value) { m_value = value; };

      void setFixedFlag(bool flag) { m_is_fixed = flag; };

      // INQUIRIES
      bool isFixed() const { return m_is_fixed; };

   };

private:
   static const int m_row_size = 9;
   static const int m_col_size = 9;
   Square m_board [m_row_size][m_col_size];
   int m_num_variable_entries = 0;

public:
   // CONSTRUCTOR
   Puzzle() { setSquares(); };

   // DESTRUCTOR
   ~Puzzle() {};

   // ACCESSORS
   int size() const { return m_num_variable_entries; };

   int numEmpty();

   void display(std::ostream& out) const;

   int get(int const row, int const col) const { return m_board[row][col].getValue(); };

   // MUTATORS
   bool set(int const row, int const col, int const value);

   // FACILITATORS
   void input(std::istream& in);

   bool solvePuzzle(int row = 0, int col = 0);   

public:
   // FRIENDS
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Puzzle& puzzle);

   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Puzzle& puzzle);

private:
   // MUTATORS
   void setSquares();

   int convertCharToInt(char const c) { return int(c) - 48; };

   // FACILITATORS
   int nextRow(int const row, int const col) const { return (col == m_col_size - 1) ? row + 1 : row; };

   int nextCol(int const col) const { return (col + 1) % m_col_size; };

   // INQUIRIES
   bool isRowLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const;

   bool isColLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const;

   bool isBoxLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const;

   bool isLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const;

};
```

### Implementation

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Puzzle.h"

// CONSTRUCTOR

// ACCESSORS
int Puzzle::numEmpty() {
   int num_empty = 0;
   for (int row = 0; row < m_row_size; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < m_col_size; col++) {
         if (m_board[row][col].getTrueValue() == 0) {
            num_empty++;
         }
      }
   }
   return num_empty;
}

void Puzzle::display(std::ostream& out) const {
   for (int row = 0; row < m_row_size; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < m_col_size; col++) {
         // cout col divider between blocks for given cols
         if (col == 3 || col == 6) {
            std::cout << "|";
         }
         else {
            std::cout << " ";
         }
         std::cout << m_board[row][col].getTrueValue();
      }
      // cout row divider between blocks for given rows
      if (row == 2 || row == 5) {
         std::cout << std::endl;
         const int front = 0;
         const int end = 18;
         for (int i = front; i < end + 1; i++) {
            if (i % 6 == 0 && i != front && i != end) {
               std::cout << "+";
            }
            else {
               std::cout << "-";
            }
         }
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
}

// MUTATORS
void Puzzle::setSquares() {
   m_num_variable_entries = 0;

   for (int row = 0; row < m_row_size; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < m_col_size; col++) {
         if (m_board[row][col].getTrueValue() == 0) {
            m_board[row][col].setFixedFlag(false);
         }
         else {
            ++m_num_variable_entries;
            m_board[row][col].setFixedFlag(true);
         }
      }
   }
}

bool Puzzle::set(int const row, int const col, int const val) {
   if (isLegal(row, col, val)) {
      m_board[row][col].setValue(val);
      return true;
   }
   else {
      return false;
   }
}

// FACILITATORS
void Puzzle::input(std::istream& in) {

   m_num_variable_entries = 0;
   char c;
   int row = 0;
   int col = 0;
   while (in >> c) {
      if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
         int num = convertCharToInt(c);
         m_board[row][col].setValue(num);
         if (c == '0') {
            m_board[row][col].setFixedFlag(false);
         }
         else {
            m_board[row][col].setFixedFlag(true);
            m_num_variable_entries++;
         }
         row = nextRow(row, col);
         col = nextCol(col);
      }
      if (row == 9) {
         break;
      }
   }
}

bool Puzzle::solvePuzzle(int row, int col) {
   int next_row = nextRow(row, col);
   int next_col = nextCol(col);

   if (row == 9) {
      return true;
   }

   if (m_board[row][col].isFixed()) {
      return solvePuzzle(next_row, next_col);
   }

   for (int val = 1; val <= 9; val++) {

      if (set(row, col, val) && solvePuzzle(next_row, next_col)) {
         return true;
      }
      else {
         m_board[row][col].setValue(0);
      }
   }
   return false;
}

// INQUIRIES
bool Puzzle::isRowLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const {
   // iterate through a row and skip the square we're confirming
   // check for existing equivalent value.
   for (int i = 0; i < m_col_size; i++) {
      if (i != col && m_board[row][i].getTrueValue() == val) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}

bool Puzzle::isColLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const {
   // iterate through a col and skip the square we're confirming
   // check for existing equivalent value.
   for (int i = 0; i < m_row_size; i++) {
      if (i != row && m_board[i][col].getTrueValue() == val) {
         return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}

bool Puzzle::isBoxLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const {
   int const row_corner = (row / 3) * 3;
   int const col_corner = (col / 3) * 3;

   for (int i = row_corner; i < (row_corner + 3); i++) {
      for (int j = col_corner; j < (col_corner + 3); j++) {
         if ((i != row || j != col) && m_board[i][j].getTrueValue() == val) {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
   return true;
}

bool Puzzle::isLegal(int const row, int const col, int const val) const {
   return (isRowLegal(row, col, val) &&
           isColLegal(row, col, val) &&
           isBoxLegal(row, col, val));
}

// FRIENDS
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Puzzle& puzzle) {
   puzzle.display(out);
   return out;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, Puzzle& puzzle) {
   puzzle.input(in);
   return in;
}
```

Comment: `0110...` counts as invalid input because of the duplicate ones, right?

Comment: That's right. It should return false. But the method gets stuck in an infinite loop instead.

Comment: I would suggest that input validation should be separate from solving the puzzle.
But looking at your code, I think the issue is that `isRowLegal` only checks the current square against one square at a time, so it doesn't notice that there are two fixed 1s. I would probably keep track of all fixed values seen in the row so far and if a duplicate is seen then I'd raise an exception indicating that the input is invalid.
Same for `isBoxLegal` and `isColLegal`.

Comment: I checked the debugger to see if the the `isRowLegal`, `isBoxLevel`, and `isColLegal` and does return false when relevant it seems.

the methods as I've written them iterate through every relevant cell and make sure it doesn't match the value that's attempting to be inserted. 

I believe the logic detects that something is wrong... but the recursive method is not exiting as I thought it would. 

Perhaps the best solution is as you suggested to create a test that the board is legal to begin with.

Comment: `isRowLegal` doesn't do what it says on the tin. It only checks that your *move* does not introduce a new duplicate. It doesn't check that there were no duplicates before the move. You want a separate function to check that (once, before the game starts). Same about all other checking functions.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments to my question by @n. m. and @Matt Clarke, the `isLegal` call only checks that a given input is not duplicated. There is not a check for duplicated entries already existing in the board.

So in my input method, I've added a check that still utilizes the logic of the `isLegal` method.

I also made my `solvePuzzle` method private, the method can be called as helper method once we've verified the puzzle is solvable.

```cpp
bool Puzzle::isPuzzleLegal() const {
   for (int row = 0; row < m_row_size; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < m_col_size; col++) {
         if (m_board[row][col].isFixed()) {
            bool result = isLegal(row, col, m_board[row][col].getTrueValue());
            if (!result) {
               return false;
            }
         }
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```